# Python 3 if/elif issue

Tags: qpython3

i have a if/elif statement in my code snippet below... for some reason even when i trigger the elif statement the console still prints the if statement instead of the elif... i'm sure i am missing something stupid.

> use_stim = str.lower(input("Do you want to use this stimpak now?"))

```
    if "ok" in use_stim or "okay" in use_stim or "yes" in use_stim or "sure" in use_stim or "you bet" or "good idea" in use_stim:
        char_health = char_health + char_stim_heal
        char_stims = char_stims - 1
        print(char_name + ": Using stimpak, I feel better")  
        print("")
        print("***STATS***")
        print("Health:" + str(char_health)) 
        print("Stimpaks:" + str(char_stims))
        print("***STATS***")
        print("")            
        search_next = str.lower(input(char_name + ": Alright, what's next? Weapons or amunition?"))
        print(username + ": " + search_next)

    elif "no" in use_stim or "nope" in use_stim or "never" in use_stim or "no way" in use_stim or "not a chance" in use_stim or "i don't think so" in use_stim:
        print(user_name + ": " + use_stim)
        print(char_name + ": Alright, i'll save it for later.")
        char_stims = 1
        char_health = 75
        print("")
        print("***STATS***")
        print("Health:" + str(char_health)) 
        print("Stimpaks:" + str(char_stims))
        print("***STATS***")
        print("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're missing an `in use_stim` in the first if statement after the `"You bet"`;

```
  if "ok" in use_stim or "okay" in use_stim or "yes" in use_stim or "sure" in use_stim or "you bet" in use_stim or "good idea" in use_stim:
        char_health = char_health + char_stim_heal
        char_stims = char_stims - 1
        print(char_name + ": Using stimpak, I feel better")  
        print("")
        print("***STATS***")
        print("Health:" + str(char_health)) 
        print("Stimpaks:" + str(char_stims))
        print("***STATS***")
        print("")            
        search_next = str.lower(input(char_name + ": Alright, what's next? Weapons or amunition?"))
        print(username + ": " + search_next)

    elif "no" in use_stim or "nope" in use_stim or "never" in use_stim or "no way" in use_stim or "not a chance" in use_stim or "i don't think so" in use_stim:
        print(user_name + ": " + use_stim)
        print(char_name + ": Alright, i'll save it for later.")
        char_stims = 1
        char_health = 75
        print("")
        print("***STATS***")
        print("Health:" + str(char_health)) 
        print("Stimpaks:" + str(char_stims))
        print("***STATS***")
        print("")
```

This should work now.

A couple of notes for you if you want;

- You can add the extra line between print statements using `/n` so you can remove the `print("")` statements and add `\n` to the previous statement e.g;

  ```
  print(char_name + ": Using stimpak, I feel better\n") <<< Add \n here  
  print("")                                             <<< Remove this
  print("***STATS***")
  print("Health:" + str(char_health)) 
  print("Stimpaks:" + str(char_stims))
  print("***STATS***\n")                                <<< Add \n here 
  print("")                                             <<< Remove this
  ```
- The use of `in` will search for the text you've specified *anywhere* in the string, so `"no" in use_stim` will work for `no`, `nope`, `no way` and `not a chance`, therefore you can simplify the `elif` statement to;

`elif "no" in use_stim or "never" in use_stim  or "i don't think so" in use_stim:`

Comment: oh man... i cant believe I missed that... rookie mistake... as a beginner programmer your notes help me a lot and I will definitely implement them into my code...thanks a lot

Comment: Happens to the best of us! And not a problem at all, glad to help :)

Comment: Matt, I tried the /n method like in your example but it's not working. It just prints /n as part of the string instead of making a new line. I am using qPython on my phone. Might be an issue with the IDE?

Comment: Sorry @Stagger I'm not sure why it wouldn't interpret it as a newline and I'm not too familiar with qPython, there could well be a way to change the settings to interpret the `/n` as a newline within qPython itself. If not then revert back to printing nothing, it's not exactly bad code it just cleans it up slightly!

Comment: i found the problem...it's \n not /n

Comment: ...sorry @Stagger, indeed it is.. I shouldn't answer questions before having a coffee..

Comment: You still helped me a lot and solved my problem... imagine what you can do after coffee.